# Firebase firestore wont delete collection made from macos

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

This is an ongoing issue with macos, everytime i create a firebase collection i can't delete it.

These are the issue:
Even though there are no documents in firestore, it will still show on my flutter app when i run it, looks like it is holding onto some cache or sth.

Then when i try to delete it from the firestore manually it will get stuck.
This is causing me to recreate a new project everytime because i just can't delete the firestore collection what is the issue here?

it is stuck on delete this collection..?

This is how I am trying to delete is with code as I couldn't do it manually

```dart
  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    // await FirebaseServices.uploadInitialData();
    final CollectionReference cabinCrewCollection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CABIN_CREW_DATA');
    try {
      await cabinCrewCollection.get().then((snapshot) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.docs) {
          ds.reference.delete();
        }
      });
      print('CABIN_CREW_DATA collection deleted successfully.');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error deleting CABIN_CREW_DATA collection: $e');
    }

    // await FirebaseServices.getCaptainData();
    // await FirebaseServices.getFirstOfficerData();
    // await FirebaseServices.getCabinCrewData();
    //await FirebaseServices.fetchTrainingData();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

the console

```
Toast message for the web: You are logged in
CABIN_CREW_DATA collection deleted successfully.
2
Stream builder called
updategrid called 1
[2023-08-28T16:19:53.417Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:19:53.423Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:20:52.048Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:20:52.049Z]  @firebase/firestore:
```

If you see, the log tells me it has been deleted successfully but it is persistent in firestore, this is called repeatedly

```
[2023-08-28T16:19:53.417Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:19:53.423Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:20:52.048Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:20:52.049Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:21:40.820Z]  @firebase/firestore:
[2023-08-28T16:21:40.821Z]  @firebase/firestore:
```

And when i try to delete manually it is stuck on progress indicator for deletion.

For some reason I do believe that the data is already deleted but still shows in firestore.
[image]

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Firebase console, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to let them know what's going wrong.  We almost certainly can't help you with that.  As for your Flutter app, you certainly do have source code to share if a query isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Is there any error message or relevant warning showing in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen   updated the question , please take a second look. Yes I have submitted to Firebase support but yet to receive any answers.

Comment: So how are you observing the problem?  You have code to delete documents, but you aren't showing anything that illustrates that the documents are not actually deleted.  I'll point out that you're not awaiting the result of each `delete()` nor are you checking the results for errors.

Comment: @DougStevenson i am going directly to firebase console from my browser and deleting the collection `CABIN_CREW_DATA` but it is stuck on the delete screen with the progress bar spinning forever as shown in the picture. The code i posted was to check if I get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to Google representatives, this is a issue that might persist and the answer is to go to [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/firestore/databases?authuser=1&supportedpurview=project) to remove it.